# Dreamweaver creating temp php files instead of working direct from the local test server files

Tags: php, localhost, dreamweaver, mamp, temp

Trying to get MAMP running with Dreamweaver.

When I preview a php file inside Dreamweavers 'Live View' mode instead of working direct from my file:

http://localhost/php_test/timetest.php

it creates its own temp file which looks like:

http:// 127.0.0.1/php_test/ TMPWY5ZEM.php

(I've added the additional spaces as stockoverflow assumed I was spamming)

I know the localhost runs correctly as if I type the URL directly into a browser it runs fine.

I've set up the Dreamweaver site correctly to the best of my knowledge, the details are below:

Local site folder:
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php_test

Server Folder:
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php_test

Web URL:
http://localhost/php_test/

Testing Server:
PHP MySQL

Any help?

Comment: I don't think you're gonna find many people who use DreamWeaver on this site....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This typically means that you have the preview using temporary file preference set (which I believe may be a default setting). Do the following:
Edit (Dreamweaver on Mac) Preferences, Preview in Browser category, uncheck Preview using temporary file

Answer (score 0):

setup a testing server, if you have some problems from there, set your site type to localhost.